# Web master tools showing 404 for /a in Kohana based sites?

Tags: jquery, http-status-code-404, google-search-console

I have noticed when working with various Kohana sites that webmaster tools almost always flags up `/a` as 404'ing. I have no specific code to show you because it occurs in pretty much all of them.

I just wondered if anyone else had or has fixed this problem. Is it a known issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, i just noticed this behaviour for some of my websites, running on different hosts and cms, among them wordpress. Couldn't find the links on there, though... maybe it's just a Webmaster Tools Bug? Or did you come to any solution?

Comment: I think redirecting them with a 301 did the trick but I can't be sure. Because I have moved to a static site. Since I have then it has stopped so it is either down to the 301 or Kohana.

Comment: for me this was caused by jQuery.  See my answer above.

Comment: Google knows about it and it's caused by jQuery.  See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749348/jquery-causing-404-errors-in-webmaster-tools-on-a-directory) and this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416081/404-errors-on-a-folders-in-webmaster-tools) to read Google's response.

Comment: Issue has nothing to do with php or kohana, perhaps those tags should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide some more information.

Is `/a` a valid location in your website? Of course it's going to flag `/a` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: No, it says it is linked to from every page, in multiple web sites that never link to /a. /a does not exist and is not linked to by any page. Maybe it is a problem with web master tools?

Comment: Hmm, that's very strange. Have you tried viewing the page as Google bot? You can find the option in the webmaster tools. A possibility is some malware has infected your website and is only displaying itself to Google.

Comment: I doubt it can be malware, unless the same one has infected multiple completely unrelated servers and websites. I have seen it on pretty much every Kohana base site.

Comment: This `href="/a"` definitely coming from jQuery as confirmed by looking at [the jQuery source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js).  This has also been [confirmed as a known issue by a Google employee](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?fid=3102f0a5f6e219ac0004a1f75422344b&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is the root source of the code being picked up by the Googlebot.  Within the jQuery file itself is this line...

```
<a href='/a' style='color:red;float:left;opacity:.55;'>a</a>
```

As per Google (see below), add a 301 redirect to the `htaccess` file to kill this problem for good.

```
Redirect 301  /a  http://www.mySite.com
```

The following is a response from Google employee JohnMu on this issue in [the thread I started at Google Groups](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?fid=3102f0a5f6e219ac0004a1f75422344b&hl=en).

> JohnMu
>
> Google Employee
>
> 4:39 AM
>
> Hi guys
>
> Just a short note on this -- **yes, we
> are picking up the "/a" link for many
> sites from jQuery JavaScript. However,
> that generally isn't a problem, if we
> see "/a" as being a 404, then that's
> fine for us.** As with other 404-URLs,
> we'll list it as a crawl error in
> Webmaster Tools, but again, that's not
> going to be a problem for crawling,
> indexing, or ranking. If you want to
> make sure that it doesn't trigger a
> crawl error in Webmaster Tools, then I
> would recommend just 301 redirecting
> that URL to your homepage (disallowing
> the URL will also bring it up as a
> crawl error - it will be listed as a
> URL disallowed by robots.txt).
>
> I would also recommend not explicitly
> disallowing crawling of the jQuery
> file. While we generally wouldn't
> index it on its own, we may need to
> access it to generate good Instant
> Previews for your site.
>
> So to sum it up: If you're seeing "/a"
> in the crawl errors in Webmaster
> Tools, you can just leave it like
> that, it won't cause any problems. **If
> you want to have it removed there, you
> can do a 301 redirect to your
> homepage.**
>
> Cheers
>
> John

See this SO answer for even more information:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6587142/594235