# Facebook Like button code causes HTML validation errors

Tags: html, validation, facebook-like

I've incorporated an Iframe 'Like' button into every page of my website - http://www.newforestexplorersguide.co.uk - but the Facebook code causes a number of HTML validation errors (XHTML 1.0 Transitional). 
The 'Like' button works fine, but do I need to be concerned about the validation errors? I'm particularly bothered about Google rankings, which I know can be affected by the presence of errors.
Thanks in advance for advice.
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"... do I need to be concerned about the validation errors? I'm
>   particularly bothered about Google rankings, which I know can be
>   affected by the presence of errors."*

I took a peak at your code and the [Validation Errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.newforestexplorersguide.co.uk&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

There are clever ways, using JavaScript, to achieve perfect Validation while using the Facebook Like button code.  I've done it on my sites.  However, in reality, it only causes the online Validator to pass the static file through without errors.  When you use JavaScript to manipulate your HTML, the DOM will ultimately end up with the same code as if you did nothing to fix the errors.

As far as Google is concerned, yes, valid HTML/CSS matters.  Lately, Google's bots are even able to parse jQuery/JavaScript in order to index more dynamic content.  [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416081/404-errors-on-a-folders-in-webmaster-tools/5748313#5748313) to read a response from Google on this.

Although, concerned with coding errors, it seems that Google is able to discriminate between the severity of errors.  After all, **every** site using Facebook's stock plugins will be in the same boat as yourself with slightly invalid code.

For your site in particular, using outdated coding practices, like `tables` for page layouts on the entire site is far more detrimental to your Google ranking than anything else.  They are slower for the bots to parse than pure CSS layouts, and since Google rankings now take page load times into consideration, it would be a good idea to become as streamlined and modern as possible.

Finally, by far, more important than anything else, is your site's content and its presentation.  Google Search is a business with one goal, to provide the most relevant & useful results for a particular search term.  The best code in the world will not help the rankings of a site that forgets this principle.

Comment: As a further comment, I wonder why Facebook don't provide error-free code to the benefit of all users?

Comment: @AndrewWalmsley, it annoys me too, but with 800 million users, they will do whatever they please.   Non-compliant `allowtransparency` within the `iframe` code is only there for IE and will function elsewhere without it.  And the `<meta property=` can be renamed as `<meta name=` to be compliant and still function as far as the Facebook Lint Tool is concerned.  This is not the place for discussion, so I'll leave it there.

Comment: Hi again. I'm fairly new to this forum. How do I 'accept' the answer?

Comment: @AndrewWalmsley, there is a checkmark upper-left to the answer.  You just click on that after waiting the specified amount of time.  More info here:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask