# Why does http://validator.w3.org evaluate page before jQuery? alt tags?

Tags: jquery, html, w3c-validation

I have a page with a dynamically generated slideshow of images via jQuery(). The images were uploaded by end-users as WordPress posts. Most of them were lazy and did not include any ALT tags.

I ran the page against w3c validator and naturually, it complains that each image needs an ALT tag.

So I wrote a little jQuery() to dynamically add a generic ALT tag for any image that doesn't have one.

```
jQuery('img').each( function(i) 
  { 
  var v = jQuery(this).attr('alt');
    if( typeof(v) == 'undefined' )
      jQuery(this).attr('alt','generic alt tag');
} );
```

And although it appears on the source, the validator -still- complains that the images have no ALT tag. Does the w3c validator somehow 'see' the page after it's loaded but -before- the jQuery fires? Or am I missing something else completely obvious?

Is there a way to have my code fire -before- the validator? And finally, does it make any difference in the real world? IOW: are there other services (search engines, screen readers) that might fail with this technique?

Comment: Validators run before script executes on a page simply because there is no guarantee that your script is going to run at all to begin with (users can disable scripts, etc.).

Comment: Check out this [Wordpress snippet](http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-missing-alt-tags-to-wordpress-images) which adds alt tags through PHP

Comment: I don't understand why this question was voted down. Obviously, I did not understand a -concept-. Isn't this place supposed to be for clearing up confusions like this?

Comment: My guess is that is has to do with the incorrect assumptions apparently due to lack of basic research.  The whole premise of the question is flawed, however, we're now [discouraged from explaining our votes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments).

Answer (score 5):

The Markup Validation Service validates the *markup*.

It doesn't generate a DOM, execute JavaScript then validate the modified DOM.

You'll have to run the JavaScript on the server to see the effects in the validator.

> are there other services (search engines, screen readers) that might fail with this technique?

Screen readers will generally work on the generated DOM, but I suspect you'll find a higher proportion of screen reader users than non-screen reader users will disable JS in their browsers.

Search engines will generally not execute JS at all.

Comment: Thanks. I'm surprised to learn that 'Search engines will generally not execute JS at all'

Comment: Except for Google, which does consider JavaScript & jQuery to render their site previews as per Google employee John Mu.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5748313/594235

Comment: That is, however, the instant preview feature which is distinct from the indexing feature.

Answer (score 2):

> "And although it appears on the source"

No, it doesn't. You are looking at the curret state of the DOM, if you instead look at the actual source for the page, you will see it without the added attributes.

> "Does the w3c validator somehow 'see' the page after it's loaded but
>   -before- the jQuery fires?"

The jQuery doesn't fire at all. The validator loads the page and examines the HTML code. No Javascript is executed, and there isn't even a DOM created that the Jasvascript could alter.

The validator sees the page just like search engine bots do, they only load the page itself and examine that. They don't execute any Javascript, so for SEO purposes there is no point in adding `alt` attributes using Javascript.

Comment: Thanks, but when I view the 'Source' from Firefox, the alt tags generated by jQuery -do- appear. I understand your point, however.

Comment: @jchwebdev  — They should not. Are you confusing "Inspector" and "Page Source"?

Comment: @jchwebdev: When use the "View page source" option in Firefox I see the actual page source. Is that what you use?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds reasonable to me; the validator reads and checks your Html, and not the JS. That makes sense assuming the validator follows a standard, and a set of rules for a plain Html page. From that point of view, JS is an extension.

Also, imagine what would happen if a user with JS disabled visits your page - how would it work and look?

If you still want to validate the resulting Html, which a browser that processes JS will, then I suppose you could create a fake copy of the page, and modify it so it will have the same result, only in plain Html (ie remove the whole dependency on JS just for testing purposes).

On the other hand - what is really the point of this? I'm not sure validating a page just for the sake of validating it serves any purpose. If you can verify that the page looks fine in most of the main browsers, and that it also works on a small screen, then you've accomplished something a lot more meaningful than a simple W3C validation.

Comment: The only 'point' was to understand the concept a bit better. I was under the impression that search engines -do- take into account HTML generated via javascript... well, at least -some-. I see dynamically added tags all the time on various commercial sites.

Comment: @jchwebdev, inspecting the DOM and viewing the source are two completely different things.  The DOM is what you're manipulating and the HTML source is how it's generated and sent down by the server.   **It is IMPOSSIBLE to see "dynamically" generated tags in the "source".**